# Why does APPLOCK_MODE and APPLOCK_TEST return the wrong answer here?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Either I'm doing something wrong (likely), or [`APPLOCK_MODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/applock-mode-transact-sql) and [`APPLOCK_TEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/applock-test-transact-sql) sometimes return an incorrect answer.

In one tab, I run this code:

```
begin tran
  declare @lock int = -1
  exec @lock = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'testlock', @Lockmode = 'Exclusive',
    @LockOwner = 'Transaction', @LockTimeout=0

  if @lock = 0
    print 'got lock'
  else
    print 'failed to get lock' 

  waitfor delay '00:00:05'

  if @lock = 0
    exec sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'testlock', @LockOwner = 'Transaction'

  print 'released lock'
commit
```

In another tab, I run this code:

```
begin tran

  print 'APPLOCK_TEST=' + convert(varchar(max), 
      APPLOCK_TEST(suser_name(), 'testlock', 'Exclusive', 'Transaction'))
  print 'APPLOCK_MODE=' + 
      APPLOCK_MODE(suser_name(), 'testlock', 'Transaction')

  declare @lock int

  exec @lock = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'testlock', @Lockmode = 'Exclusive',
      @LockOwner = 'Transaction', @LockTimeout=0

  print 'Result=' + convert(varchar(max), @lock)

  if @lock = 0 -- lock is held
  begin
    print 'releasing lock'
    exec sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'testlock', @LockOwner = 'Transaction'
  end

commit
```

What I see when running the code in the first tab and then running the code in the second tab before the first tab completes is:

```
APPLOCK_TEST=1
APPLOCK_MODE=NoLock
Result=-1
```

The result value of `1` for `APPLOCK_TEST` and `NoLock` for `APPLOCK_MODE` both indicate that the lock is not currently in use and I should be able to get it. This is wrong, as the lock is still held by the other tab until that completes. This is confirmed by the actual call to `sp_getapplock` failing.

What's puzzling me is why those two test functions are returning the opposite of what I would expect. Is there some aspect I'm missing here?

Comment: I can confirm some (but not all) of the behavior that you're seeing. But let me ask you this: what are you trying to accomplish? Any time I've done anything with `sp_getapplock`, I just try to get the lock and deal with both getting and not getting the lock accordingly. Testing whether you can or not beforehand *seems* to create a race condition to me.

Comment: A fair question. It was really just me trying to debug why I was failing to get the lock. Before posting the question, I had found the offending spid  in sys.dm_tran_locks (I could have used sp_lock but didn't realize they were in there). But I had tried these functions on the way to get there and wanted to understand why they didn't work like I expected. As you say, my actual production code just tries to get the lock and handle it when it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be specifying `public` as the principal, not `suser_name()`, as that's also the (default) principal under which the locks are taken. `APPLOCK_TEST` will return 0 when you specify `public` (the lock isn't grantable). `APPLOCK_MODE` will still return `NoLock`, because it returns the mode of the lock held by the *current* transaction -- and the current transaction isn't holding the lock. (The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/applock-mode-transact-sql) is admittedly not clear on this, but it *does* give an example with the expected behavior.) If this seems useless, consider the fact that multiple transactions may be holding a (sharable) lock in different modes.

However, per the comment made by @BenThul, testing the lock status before acquiring it is ill advised, because it's point-in-time information that could be invalid by the time you actually attempt to take the lock. It's hard to imagine a scenario where `APPLOCK_TEST` can be used meaningfully (as opposed to `sp_getapplock` with a zero or very small timeout).

Comment: Yes, I had somehow not grokked that I was supposed to put `public` there instead of an actual username, given how the `APPLOCK_TEST` help indicated it was supposed to be "the user, role, or application role". So I was going with user. Makes perfect sense now that I know.

As for why I was using those functions in that way, see my comment above to Ben. I was really just trying to track down what spid had it locked (turned out to be a query tab where I'd run the stored proc and it had failed elsewhere, not releasing the lock, which was a session one.)

Comment: Speaking out of the other side of my mouth, I can see a scenario where you *might* want to test first. Since you know your application (and, by extension, the expected time the lock will be held), it might be worth testing before trying to obtain if you have something like only one process at a time should be trying for the lock and that lock is generally held for a long time (think a batch processing scenario). Even there though, I'd be inclined to just try to get the lock with a long timeout value.

Comment: @BenThul: because of the irksome requirement to get the principal right, even in that case I'd probably prefer `sp_getapplock` with a zero timeout to test if the lock is held & acquire it if not (followed by an `sp_getapplock` with a long timeout if I'm willing to wait). `APPLOCK_TEST` is really only worth it if you want to test *without* going for the lock at all, and scenarios where that is useful are rare (beyond debugging, where, as jep has already found out, `sp_lock` and `sys.dm_tran_locks` are tons more informative).

Comment: You could use `APPLOCK_TEST` if you want to know whether a lock is currently held. This could be useful to other code in the same transaction as a behavior flag, such as to produce an error if the lock is not held, or to control behavior in a trigger.